# How to bootstrap a chef node behind a jump box

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I am trying to bootstrap a chef node. The node is behind a jump box. Is there a way to specify jump box in the knife command

command I am trying to run

knife bootstrap 1.2.3.4 -x user --sudo --node-name example.com --bootstrap-version 12.X

it cannot connect to the node

The node was provisioned through AWS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep, use `--ssh-gateway` and give it the hostname or IP of the jump box. If the jump box isn't using the same key for authentication as the target box, you'll probably want to set up an SSH agent too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I ended up storing the configuration in the my ssh config file using the ProxyCommand Directive